# Operetion on child collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I have code like this

```
$tag = Tag::where('slug' = $slug)->first();
$posts = $tag->posts;
```

It works correctly but I want to use limit, orderBy, offset and other operation on posts. So it works

```
$posts = $tag->posts->where('accept', 1);
```

But it doesn't works

```
    $posts-> $tag->posts->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
//or
    $posts-> $tag->posts
                 ->offset($offset)
                 ->limit($limit);
```

I must use offset and limit into query from var.
How I can do that?

Comment: Does it throw any error? How do you realize that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up your initial query `Tag::where('slug' = $slug)->first();` you're using Query Builder and it's methods.  But when Laravel returns the results, they're returned as a collction object -- those have very similar but slightly different methods available.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods

On a collection or its children, instead of orderBy() you would use sortBy() or sortByDesc().  Those will return an instance of the collection, sorted by your specified key.  `$results = $posts->sortBy($sorting);`

The same idea with limit, in this case you can use the splice method.  (Collections are basically php arrays on steroids) Splice accepts two parameters, a starting index and a limit.  So, to get only the first 10 items, you could do this: $results = $posts->splice(0, 10);

And of course, you can also chain those togeather as `$results = $tag->posts->sortBy('id')->splice(0, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

When you use child, Eloquent create another subquery, then result is added to parent, thats way its not sorting properly.

A solution could be join tables:

```
$tags = Tag::where('tags.slug' = $slug)
    ->join('tags', 'tag.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
    ->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'desc')
    ->select('tags.*')
    ->get();
```